# ETA Australia after travel ban

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, australia, overstaying, eta

I previously overstayed a visa in Australia and for which I received a 3 year ban. The ban period has ended.

I have applied for and been granted an ETA visa. The visa took 4 days for its approval. Normally an ETA is instantaneous. What could be the reason for it to take so long?

Comment: Um ... besides the obvious hypothesis that your previous ban flagged your application for human review? Have you any reason to think that is _not_  the explanation?

Comment: We can only speculate, which isn't what this site is for.

Answer (score 4):

The previous ban would have flagged your application up for human review, which obviously isn't going to be instant and depending on the current amount of applications, could take quite a while.

Other reasons could include Technical Problems or another Technical Reason.